Postgres 16 Continuous archiving and PITR "invalid checkpoint" error
Here is what I am doing:

I have a Postgres 16 docker container which is continuously archiving WAL files
After 00012 and 00013 were archived, I take a base-backup of the database using pg_basebackup which generates a 00014..backup file (these are example files and actual WALs are longer I know)
Now I copy over the base backup and the archived WALs into another Postgres 16 docker container which is newly created from same docker image (including version)
I make postgres user as owner for all these files
I remove the WALs from the pg_wal directory of base backup and update the restore_command of postgresql.conf (additionally I also undo the archive configs which were there on primary)
I remove 00012 and 00013 WALs as those are already there in base backup, so now archived WALs is only 00014 and the .backup file created
I create a recovery.signal file, which is empty and in the data directory
Then finally I change the name of the current pgdata to pgdata_ini and the backup directory as pgdata so that it acts as my data directory
Then I stop the container and start again but database startup fails due to invalid checkpoint record and could not find required checkpoint record

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here?
